# More than one filter parameter in single scope in Microsoft Sync framework

Tags: c#, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

I am using Microsoft Sync service 4.0 to sync data between Ipad local database and SQL server central database.

I have used a filter "`UserId`" in the sync scope to filter the records of the table. There are several tables in the scope, all of them having the field "`UserId`".

Now, I want to include another table in the scope which does not have any "`UserId`" field, but I want to filter this new table with some other filter, say "`PublicationId`".

Can I have two filter parameters in a scope, one which will filter records from some table in the scope, and the other which will filter records from remaining tables.

This is the service call given by the Ipad client

```
https://<server name>/SyncService.svc/<scope name>/DownloadChanges?userId=1902
```

Comment: I should have tried this before. I took two tables in scope, one with filter paramater and other without. It is working perfectly

Answer (score 0):

filters are by table. you can have have many tables in a scope, so you can have as many filters.